# Full Url is not displayed in browser Flutter web

Tags: navigation, flutter-web

In my App I have setup a custom Navigator and dough the navigation system works, the browser doesn't show the full url, it always shows `http://localhost:55865/#/` ..
Can you spot what I'm doing wrong ?

I declared all routes as:

```
const String HomeRoute = '/home';
const String AboutRoute = '/about';
const String RetailerAccessRoute = '/retailers';
const String TermsOfServiceRoute = '/termsOfService';
const String PrivacyPolicyRoute = '/privacyPolicy';
const String PrivacySettingsRoute = '/privacySettings';
const String CommunityGuidelinesRoute = '/communityGuidelines';
const String LegalNoticeRoute = '/legalNotice';
```

then I have the `generateRoute` (called by `MaterialApp`'s `onGenerateRoute:` callback) that uses a switch to return the corresponding Widget with an applied transition effect:

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
//  print('generatedRoute: ${settings.name}');
  switch (settings.name) {
    case HomeRoute:
      return _getPageRoute((HomePage()));
    case AboutRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(AboutPage());
    case RetailerAccessRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(RetailerAccess());
    case TermsOfServiceRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(TermsOfService());
    case PrivacyPolicyRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(PrivacyPolicy());
    case CommunityGuidelinesRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(CommunityGuidelines());
    case LegalNoticeRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(LegalNotice());
  }
}

PageRoute _getPageRoute(Widget child) {
  return _FadeRoute(
    child: child,
  );
}

class _FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;
  _FadeRoute({this.child})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              child,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: child,
          ),
        );
}
```

`navigateTo()` method does actually push the route:

```
class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = NavigatorKeys.webNavigatorGlobalKey;
//  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  
Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName);
  }
}
```

`navigateTo()` is called inside the `NavigationBar`'s buttons(`NavigationBarItem`) `onPressed:` callback:

```
class NavigationBarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final String navigationPath;
  const NavigationBarItem({this.title, this.navigationPath});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,
      hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
      hoverElevation: 0,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightElevation: 0,
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      child:
      Text('$title',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        locator<NavigationService>().navigateTo(navigationPath);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Home route button example:

```
 NavigationBarItem(
                title: AppLocalizations.instance.text('Home'),
                navigationPath: HomeRoute,
              ),
```

MainLayout draws the Screen composed by `NavigationBar` and a passed in `Widget`.

```
class MainLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const MainLayout({Key key,this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) => Scaffold(
        drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.mobile
            ? NavigationDrawer()
            : null,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: CenteredWidget(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              NavigationBar(),
              Expanded(
                child: Navigator(
                  key: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
                  onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
                  initialRoute: CyclistsLandingRoute,
                ),
//              child:child,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In `main() MaterialApp` I return `MainLayout` if platform is web or the actually app if platform is not web :

```
        home: UniversalPlatform.isWeb
            ? MainLayout()
            : RetailerAccess(),
``
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add route name to settings when calling super. Change `_FadeRoute` as shown below, after change:

```
class _FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
    final Widget child;
    String route;

    _FadeRoute({this.child, this.route})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              child,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: child,
          ),
          settings: RouteSettings(name: route)
        );
}
```

in main method

```
MaterialApp(
    ...
     builder: (context, child) {
            return MainTemplateLayout(
              child: child,
            );
      },
      navigatorKey: RouterNavigationService().navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      initialRoute: "/",
...
```

and in MainTemplateLayout

```
build(BuildContext context){
...
  Container(
    child: child, // this is child passed to MainTemplate
  ) 
}
...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I actually changed a bit 'main()` as passing a `builder` , a `navigationKey`, `onGenerateRoute`, and `initialRoute` causes to always start on the specified initial route, invalidating the platform check. I tried performing the platform check on the `initialRoute` but Navigator is looking for route named "\" which doesn't exist. Unfortunately the solution you suggested is not fixing my problem, not sure if it is for the changes I made..

Comment: Hi Try moving your MaterialApp builder method to main() and in your MainTemplate simply pass the child. it should work. updated code is above. You can change initialRoute as per your change

Comment: Hi and thanks again, unfortunately is not working , declaring the initialRoute as "/" I end up with a double Navigation bar and a white page, then if I click one one the nav bar button then it goes normal.. one nav bar, but still no full route name in the browser..

Answer (score 0):

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  print('generateRoute: ${settings.name}');
  switch ('${settings.name}') {
    case HomeRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(const HomePage(), settings);
    case UsersRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(const UsersPage(), settings);
    case ProductsRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(const ProductsPage(), settings);
     case LoginRoute:
      return _getPageRoute(const LoginPage(), settings);
     default:
      return _getPageRoute(const LoginPage(), settings);
  }
}

PageRoute _getPageRoute(Widget child, RouteSettings settings) {
  return MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: settings,
    builder: (context) => child
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).